# ElasticSearch edgeNgrams with Fuzzy creates problems on scoring

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic and I am cuurently satisfied with my searches relevance except of one ocassion.For example If I am searching for the world "play" I will get docs containing wold "plays" with higher score than these ones with word "play".And that happens because I am using edgeNgrams(on indexing) with Fuzziness.Auto(on searching).Is there any filter or method to boost the exact ones than the fuzzy ones?

Here is code for indexing

```
var response = client.CreateIndex(index, s => s
.Settings(s1 => s1.NumberOfShards(1).NumberOfReplicas(1)
.Analysis(a => a.TokenFilters(t => t.EdgeNGram("edge", ed => ed.MaxGram(50).MinGram(1).Side(EdgeNGramSide.Front))
.Lowercase("lowercase", gl => gl.Language(Language.Greek.ToString())).KeywordMarker("keywords", gk => gk.Keywords("")))
.Analyzers(a1 => a1.Custom("forindex", t => t.Tokenizer("standard")
.Filters("edge", "lowercase", "keywords" ))
.Custom("forsearch", cu => cu.Tokenizer("standard")
.Filters("lowercase", "keywords"))))));
```

And here for searching

```
var query = new MatchQuery()
                        {
                            Query = searchWord,
                            Operator = Operator.And,
                            Field = fieldName,
                            Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
                            PrefixLength = 1,
                            Analyzer = "forsearch"
                        };
```

Comment: You can index the field as a multi-field and apply an analyzer with edgengram to sub field and standard analyzer to field. Now at search time, build a `bool` query that combines both (maybe the standard analyzed field in a `must` clause and the edgengram analyzed field in a `should` clause). This is just one approach but there are many many other possibilities :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I prefer to leave it like that than indexing it as a multi-field.

Comment: I don't see other option here than the one @RussCam suggested. Having multi-fields for various "ways" of scoring a field is very common in Elasticsearch world.